# How to get overall p-value in multinomial regression after MICE on R

Tags: categorical-data, p-value, multinomial-distribution, mice, variable

I run multinomial regression after multiple imputation in R. This is a GEE multinomial model with a survey design :

```
#svydesign for multinomial GEE model :

miponder_nalert <- svydesign(data = myimp.data_nalert, ids = ~enr_reg_fam,  weights = ~ponder)

#Model :

m2 <- with(miponder_nalert, svy_vglm(overall5y~agn_range, family = multinomial(refLevel = "0")))
```

I got, the pooled coefficients, OR at $95\%$ CI, and p-value for each classes of my categorical variable (agn_range).
My problem is that I would like to have the overall p-value which describes whether my variable is significant, not just a p-value for each classes for a categorical variable.

Comment: How would you do it with a binary logistic regression or even a regular OLS regression? // I disagree with the close vote. How to program this in `R` is off-topic, but there is a statistical lesson to be taught here.

Comment: I have the same problem for a classic binary, whether I need to obtain overall p-value for the categorical covariates after MICE (I tried  before). I don't have the solution.

Comment: I'd suggest starting by reading the section on multi-parameter inference from van Buuren's book, https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-multiparameter.html. Then depending on how you understand that you can ask specific questions about those methods or about your specific scenario.

Comment: See Thomas Lumley's response here, https://www.appsloveworld.com/r/100/316/how-to-get-global-p-for-categorical-variables-in-svy-vglm

Comment: In a nutshell, index<-51:56
beta<-coef(model)[index]
V<-vcov(model)[index,index]
teststat <- crossprod(beta, solve(V,beta))
pf(teststat, df1=length(beta), df2=degf(design), lower.tail=FALSE)